# java beginner: which is preferred when class has arraylist of arraylist (clone(), unmodifiable list,custom deepcopying)

Tags: java, list, matrix, copy, arraylist

I have a class Matrix which contains `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> matrix;` inside, and I want to know which is preferred when I want to copy instances of that class.

1. Should I implement clone
2. Use unmodifiable list HINT I don't know how to do that on an ArrayList
3. Do custom `copyEntries(){return Matrix(this);` , and a copy constructor `(Matrix other)`

P.S

1. I'm flexible if there was a better type recommendation like vector of vector
2. if `List<List<Double>>` and then new `ArrayList<Double>` is that better ?
3. I've used Apache commons, and some other libs but at the end I found It should be custom made matrix class.

Comment: Which is preffered when you want to do what?

Comment: I want to copy instances of this class

Comment: Thanks for asking I edited the question for more clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you try to do is to copy the matrix, bear in mind `Double` is unmodifiable so, it doesn't make much sense, creating new instances.  You can freely copy the references using something like:

<strike>List> copy = new ArrayList>();
     copy.addAll( original );</strike>

Then you can modify any of the elements and the original won't be changed:

```
copy.get( 0 ) .get( 0 ) = -1.0; 

// original at ( 0,0 ) remains the same ...
```

Ok, I get my compiler and created a running sample to probe my point of not cloning the values.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CopyMatrix { 
    public static void main( String [] args ) { 

        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.add( Arrays.asList(0.0, 1.0, 2.0 ));
        m.add( Arrays.asList(3.0, 4.0, 5.0 ));
        m.add( Arrays.asList(6.0, 7.0, 8.0 ));

        System.out.println("m = \n" +  m );

        Matrix m1 = m.copy() ;

        m1.get( 0 ).set( 0 , 100.0 );
        m1.get( 2 ).set( 2 , -400.0 );


        System.out.printf( "After m = %n %s %n m1 = %n %s %n", m, m1);
    }
}
class Matrix extends ArrayList<List<Double>> {
    public Matrix copy() {
        Matrix copy = new Matrix();
        for( List<Double> each : this ) { 
            copy.add( new ArrayList<Double>( each ) );
        }
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 java CopyMatrix 
m = 
[[0.0, 1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0, 5.0], [6.0, 7.0, 8.0]]
After m = 
 [[0.0, 1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0, 5.0], [6.0, 7.0, 8.0]] 
 m1 = 
 [[100.0, 1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0, 5.0], [6.0, 7.0, -400.0]]
```

It works!!

Comment: I don't even know if that compiles, let me get my compiler .. hold on

Comment: Doubles are immutable but ArrayLists are not.

Comment: @hhachik So true, I miss that part. Still my original answer of not copying the doubles remain, I'll update my answer

Comment: I really like the hint of extending ArrayList<List<Double> directly, instead of declaring a variable inside the class.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use

```
class Matrix implements Cloneable {
```

Then, in the clone method:

```
matrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>(other.matrix.size());
for(ArrayList<Double> vector:other.matrix){
    matrix.add(vector.clone());
}
```

Comment: There is if ismail plans to modify matrix in one instance but not in another.

Comment: @dpyz, yes i will of course modify it, but can you clarify your code please ? cause I don't know where <Matrix> goes

Comment: That's part of the class declaration.  Sorry, I left out the word class.  I'll edit it.

Comment: sorry but it says (The type Cloneable is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <matrix> )

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  I was mixing up Cloneable and Comparable